# svd $D^2$ trace and relation bw $A A'$

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

Let $E=D^2$ be a  square of diagonal matrix D in a n SVD decomposition 
$$A=UDV' $$
Find relationship bw trace D and that of $AA'$ when $A_{Nxt}$. THE $Nxt$ data matrix where $N<t$

---

Data Matrix A is decompostion into 
$$ A_{nxt}=U_{nxm}D_{mxm}V'_{mxt}$$
where n is spatial dimension $t$,t temporal length $m=min(n,t)$, adn $V'$ the transpose of v

- U spatial pattern matrix
- D diagonal level matrix
- V temporal matrix
  computing $A A^t$
  $$\begin{aligned}
  A A^t &= [UDV'][UDV']^t
       \\ &=[UDV'][V'^t D^t U^t]
       \\ &= UDV^tVD^t U^t &&\text{ using comment }
        \\ &= UDID^tU^t
        \\ &= UDD^tU^t
    \\ &= UD^2U^t &&\text{ U have eigenvecteros in it}
  \\  &= \vdots
  \end{aligned} $$

  From strang's book $$A^t A = V 
  \begin{Bmatrix} 
  \delta^2_1 && 0 \\ 0 && \delta^2_2
  \end{Bmatrix}  V^t$$
  where $\delta$ are eigenvalues , $v$ are eigenvectors

Guessing that Trace of $E=tr(AA^t)$

***have trouble make an elegant argument. Thinking need to simplify $A A^t$ with the properites of the decompose matrix***

Comment: Since $V$ is orthogonal, what can you say about $V^{T}V$?

Comment: Are you aware that $\mbox{tr}(ABC)=\mbox{tr}(CAB)$?

Comment: @BrianBorchers $V^t V$ will Identyty matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $A=UDV^T$ where $V^TV=I$ and $U^TU=I$, $D$ is diagonal ($D^T=D$), and $U$ and $V$ are unitary (i.e. $U^T=U^{-1}$ and $V^T=V^{-1}$).

Then  $$AA^T=(UDV^T)(UDV^T)^T=UDV^TVDU^T=UD^2U^T$$
Finally, since generally $\text{tr}(XY)=\text{tr}(YX)$, we have 
$$\text{tr}(AA^T)=\text{tr}(U(D^2U^T))=\text{tr}((D^2U^T)U)=\text{tr}(D^2)$$